# Using window.onload to submit a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to submit a form when the page loads. I have tried quite a few different things and none of them seem to work. If I use

```
window.onload = function(){
    alert("test");  
}
```

It works fine but when I try to use

```
window.onload = function(){
    console.log($("#testForm")[0].submit)​, 2000);  
}
```

or

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("testForm").submit();
}
```

It no longer works.

JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("testForm").submit();
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="testForm" id="testForm" method="POST" action="test.php">

    <input name="MERGE1" type="text" id="fname" size="40" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" />
    <input name="MERGE2" type="text" id="lname" size="40" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>" />
    <input name="MERGE0" type="text" id="email" size="40" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
    <input name="MERGE3" type="text" id="company" size="40" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" />
    <input name="MERGE6" type="text" id="phone" size="40" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" />
    <input name="MERGE19" type="text" id="city" size="40" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" />
    <input name="Continue" type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

Comment: console.log($("#testForm")[0].submit)​}, 2000);  - there's syntax error. are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Sorry, that was because I tried to use setTimeout to add a pause and see if that helped. I removed it from this post

Comment: it should work... can you provide jsfiddle or give us url to this page?

Comment: Are you aware that `window.onload =` overwrites any previous onload event handler attached to the `window` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#testForm").submit()
```

I replaced the POST with a GET and the action with a working URL so you can see something happening.

### [**Working fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/pgdtf/)